# Erro ao criar banco de dados com sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Colegas,

estou tentando criar banco de dados em um computador com o **Sqlite**. Ele está instalado e tudo OK, porém ao tentar criar usando o comando pelo **cmd**:

> C:\Users\José Roberto>sqlite3 C:\Users\José
>   Roberto\Desktop\database\sistema.db

Aparece esse erro:

> Error: unable to open database "C:\Users\JosÚ": unable to open
>   database file

Alguém saberia porque esse erro acontece? A meu entender, parece que o acento no nome José pode ser o problema.

Comment: cara, coloca a sua pasta database na raiz da pasta users e tenta pra ver se vai dar certo

Comment: Perfeito Henricão. Funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: vou dar uma resposta aqui só pra não ficar sem nada, que bom que ajudou

Comment: Talvez a resposta tenha resolvido o "sintoma", mas não o problema, mas a solução é um pouco mais "embaixo". Experimentou apenas sqlite3 Desktop\Database\sistema.db estando nesta pasta? Se a pagina de código do CMD for a mesma da aplicação, não é pra ter erro. Agora, que é sempre melhor evitar acentos e caracteres especiais em caminhos, é.

Comment: O problema é simplesmente o espaço no nome da pasta. No prompt de comando do Windows, pastas com espaço no nome precisam ser referenciadas entre aspas. Isso aqui vai funcionar: `C:\Users\José Roberto>sqlite3 "C:\Users\José Roberto\Desktop\database\sistema.db"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro pode estar no caminho da pasta, pelo fato do cmd ter problemas com acento, passe sua pasta para a raiz que irá funcionar, o problema encontra-se no nome mesmo.

Comment: O problema não é o acento, mas sim o espaço no nome da pasta. Basta referenciar o caminho entre aspas que tudo funciona, mesmo com acento. Assim: `C:\Users\José Roberto>sqlite3 "C:\Users\José Roberto\Desktop\database\sistema.db"`